# Behaviour Models in Fake framework

Tags: visual-studio-2012, moles, microsoft-fakes

In Visual Studio 2010, here was way to [test ASP.NET application with Behaviors](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesaspnet.pdf).Now, in VS 2012, they have upgrade to Fakes Framework. How do you achieve the same with Fakes?

Creating Fakes assembly for “System.Web” doesn’t create behavior models for “System.Web”. i.e. I can’t find `Bhttpcontext` object which use to be there when you moles “System.Web” assembly in “System.Web.Behaviors” namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moles behaviors are not included with Fakes in Visual Studio 2012. [SharePoint Emulators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/26/introducing-sharepoint-emulators.aspx) offer similar functionality, however, System.Web emulators are not public at this time. As a workaround, you can implement emulators with shims.